# Просматривать точное время написания вопросов, ответов и т. п

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Достали уже эти "2 дня назад",  "1 минуту назад" и т. д. Хочу видеть время в его нормальном виде. Ну хоть каким-то способом. А в идеале, как phpbb настройку в профиль, как отображать.

Answer (score 6):

> Ну хоть каким-то способом.

Наведите курсор на надпись "задан Х минут назад" и увидите подсказку с датой и временем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм.. А куда же я наводил, что не увидел... о_О

Comment: В любом случае, время по гринвичу - не круто. Надо местное.

Comment: @Qwertiy обсуждалось на английской мете -  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/make-recent-activity-today-etc-buttons-based-on-users-time-zone, сейчас в [tag:status-declined]

Comment: @PashaPash, во-первых, это было давно. Во-вторых, когда пост становится слишком старым и показывается время его написания как есть, оно же показвается в правильной таймзоне, значит механизм корректного отображения существует. Ну так давайте его применим! И вообще, ещё раз: я хочу настройку в профиле, как в phpbb. И больше не видеть это относительное время.

Comment: @Qwertiy для старых постов время показывыается в UTC. вот, например: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/399249/ - время на странице совпадает с временем в тултипе, оба в UTC. Существует механизм обнаружения таймзоны без настроек. "Настройка в профиле" - это самая кривая из возможных реализаций. Вопрос скорее всего в целесообразности - ну какая реально разница, 13 февраля в 13:06 или именно в 15:06 был задан этот вопрос. Важно что не вчера, и не в этом месяце.

Comment: @PashaPash, если уж я смотрю на время, когда задан вопрос, то, скорее всего, меня интересует именно время. Типа сколько прошло времени с момента, когда вопрос был задан, либо какой из ответов был дан раньше, либо в какое вообще время был дан ответ на вопрос. На классических форумах, это ещё и возможность быстро увидеть, что ничего нового не написали. А относительное время я просто ненавижу. Оно не даёт полезной информации, а только скрывает её.

Comment: @Qwertiy сколько прошло времени с момента, когда вопрос был задан - это относительное время, именно оно и показывается. вам нужно знать с точностью до минуты? зачем? в какое время был дан ответ - зачем? это влияет на качество ответа? какой из ответов был дан раньше - решается сравнением времени в UTC.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну и greasemonkey еще никто не запрещал - если уж очень хочется

Comment: @PashaPash кстати, наверняка готовое решение есть уже.

Answer (score 2):

Эта задача решается с помощью Greasemonkey-скрипта. Источник: [Display absolute timestamps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Как включить пользовательские скрипты.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info)

Я его немного модифицировал, чтобы он работал и на Ru.SO:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           localized stackoverflow timestamps
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @description    Converts relative timestamps on StackOverflow to absolute, localized timestamps. See more documentation at: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12635/
// @version        1.0-ru.so
// @match          *://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          *://serverfault.com/*
// @match          *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match          *://superuser.com/*
// @match          *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match          *://stackapps.com/*
// @match          *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match          *://stackexchange.com/*
// @match          *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match          *://askubuntu.com/*
// @match          *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match          *://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match          *://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match          *://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match          *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

  function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }; 

  with_jquery(function($) {
    //NOTE: Could be more efficient.  Need Jeff to fix this bug first:
    //  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12640/
    $("span.relativetime").each(updateTS);
    $("span.comment-date>span").each(updateTS);

    //pads number with leading 0 if needed
    function padNum(num) { return num < 10 ? "0"+num : num; }

    function updateTS() {
      var utcTimestamp = $(this).attr("title");
      var matches = utcTimestamp.match(/^([\d]{4})-([\d]{2})-([\d]{2}) ([\d]{2}):([\d]{2}):([\d]{2}) ?(?:Z|UTC|GMT(?:[+\-]00:?00))$/);

      if(matches == null)
        return;

      var date = new Date(
        Date.UTC(
          parseInt(matches[1], 10),
          parseInt(matches[2], 10) - 1,
          parseInt(matches[3], 10),
          parseInt(matches[4], 10),
          parseInt(matches[5], 10),
          parseInt(matches[6], 10)
        )
      );

      var newTimestamp = date.getFullYear() + "-"
                       + padNum(date.getMonth() + 1) + "-"
                       + padNum(date.getDate()) + " "
                       + padNum(date.getHours()) + ":"
                       + padNum(date.getMinutes()) + ":"
                       + padNum(date.getSeconds());


      $(this).attr("title", newTimestamp);
      if($(this).text().search(/(?:min|sec)s? ago/) == -1)
        $(this).text(newTimestamp);
    };

  });
})();
```